# Helper function doesn't work for coloring multiple data sets in c3.js

Tags: javascript, html, function, c3.js

I have the following javascript code to graph two data sets and have the same color scheme for each:

[here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hazpokqu/1/)

```
var chart = c3.generate({

  data: {
    x: 'Letter',
    columns:
    [
      ['Letter', 'A','B','C','D'],
      ['test', 25,50,75,100],
      ['test2', 10, 20, 30, 40]
    ],

    type: 'bar',

    colors: {
      test: function(d) {
        return '#'+(0xff0000+(d.value-25)*256*3).toString(16);
      },
      test2: function(d) {
        return '#'+(0xff0000+(d.value-25)*256*3).toString(16);
      }
    },


  },
  axis: {
    x: {
      type: 'category'
    }
  },
  legend: {
    show: false
  }
});
```

But, since both data sets have the same color scheme function, I'd like to do make the color function its own helper function and just call it twice, like this:

```
var chart = c3.generate({

  data: {
    x: 'Letter',
    columns:
    [
      ['Letter', 'A','B','C','D'],
      ['test', 25,50,75,100],
      ['test2', 10, 20, 30, 40]
    ],

    type: 'bar',

    colors: {
      test: function(d) {
        getColor(d);
      },
      test2: function(d) {
        getColor(d);
      }
    },


  },
  axis: {
    x: {
      type: 'category'
    }
  },
  legend: {
    show: false
  }
});

function getColor(d){
    return '#'+(0xff0000+(d.value-25)*256*3).toString(16);
}
```

But, [as you can see with this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hazpokqu/2/), the helper function isn't working, and I can't figure out why. I've added console print statements on my own, and the helper function is indeed returning the same values as it was when it was hard-coded into both original functions.

Is there something extremely obvious that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Is there something extremely obvious that I'm missing?"

```
   colors: {
      test: function(d) {
        RETURN getColor(d);
      },
      test2: function(d) {
        RETURN getColor(d);
      }
    },
```

I do stuff like that all the time :-)

Comment: * slams head on table * haha, well that was embarrassing. thanks!